# Guardar valor de un input checkbox

Tags: jquery, input, checkbox

Tengo un `form` donde al final del `form` tengo un `checkbox` para marcar si dicho usuario es MultiSucursal, para eso guardar su value tengo esta variable donde por medio de ajax la envio al controlador.

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '@Url.Action("Edit","Contactos")',
     data: {
     MultiSucursal: MultiSucursal
     }
```

```
<form action="/" id="frmContactoEdit" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="aZMHlJO1uQjOpac4x1_cnnqE-BWU2t00YjLBiXBeWOPncIwyBTUoXBej3BjS_TevNQSrWyoyKbtNIQCZVA9AXRDpllrsbySMFmkevjw6Iji4NH9Cuv9JHBdCQfjxnPAR5Ff5M64B3oQkv28xE-w33g2">    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card card-primary">
                <div class="card-header with-border">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Editar Contacto</h3>
                </div>
                
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <hr>
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="MultiSucursal">MultiSucursal</label>
                            <br>
                            <input class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="El campo MultiSucursal es obligatorio." id="MultiSucursal" name="MultiSucursal" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked"><input name="MultiSucursal" type="hidden" value="false" checked="checked">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="MultiSucursal" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

                        </div>

                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <input type="submit" value="Guardar" onclick="EditContacto()" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">Cancelar</span></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
var MultiSucursal = $('#MultiSucursal').val();
```

Y al momento de editar al usuario, se abre un `modal` donde por medio de `jquery` muestro los datos en los `input`´s.

```
var check = $(e.relatedTarget).data('multisucursal');
        if (check == "True") {
            $('#frmContactoEdit input[name=MultiSucursal]').attr("checked", $(e.relatedTarget).data('multisucursal'));
        }
```

Así es como muestro si esta `checked` o no. Guardo el dato en una variable y en una condición decido si darle el `checked` o no.

Y el problema es que cuando lo tengo en la tabla como `true`, se abre el `modal` y el `input` se pone como `checked`, todo bien hasta ahí... pero cuando le quito el `checked` y le guardo, no se le quita el `checked`.

Toda la info que le mando desde ajax se pasa a un controlador para posteriormente actualizar y guardar la info.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "ContactoId,SucursalId,Nombre,Correo,Departamento,Puesto,TelefonoOficina,TelefonoMovil,Activo,MultiSucursal")] Contacto contacto)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(contacto).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.SucursalId = new SelectList(db.Sucursales, "SucursalId", "Nombre", contacto.SucursalId);
            return View(contacto);
        }
```

Comment: Puedes poner el form al menos en la parte de checkbox. ¿Usas MVC? ¿Mandas los valores del POST a otro archivo?

Comment: Sí, es MVC. Los mando a un controlador que hace el update del form